# How to find the sum of the elements of an arbitrary JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

There is such an arbitrary array in which I need to find the sum of all numbers without using Array.isArray:

```
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]], [8, [9, 10]]];
```

The solution should look something like this:

```
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]; 

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
   for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) { 
      console.log(arr[i][j]);
   }
}
```

Could you please advise me on how to achieve this?

Comment: can you flatten the array and simply use `for loop` to calculate the sum ?

Comment: what about other array methods?

Comment: This requires some form of recursion or stack that can handle “N” nesting levels, at some level - the solution concept shown _will fail on the input within 3 levels of nesting_. It will also need some method to determine if an element is an array (or is not a number), even if it’s not “isArray”.

Comment: [check this](https://repl.it/repls/OutlyingSuperiorRecursion#index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Use flat and reduce methods to accomplish this.

### Example

```
let arr = [[1, 2, 
3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]], 
[8, [9, 10]]];

arr.flat(Infinity).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

## References

Flat: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: This is giving a wrong output. I think you need to pass `Infinity` as an argument to `flat()`

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array or check the instance of the given value with [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

```js
function getSum1(array) {
    return array.flat(Infinity).reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0);
}

function getSum2(array) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (const value of array) {
        sum += value instanceof Array
            ? getSum2(value)
            : value
    }
    return sum;
}

let array = [[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]], [8, [9, 10]]];

console.log(getSum1(array));
console.log(getSum2(array));
```

Answer (score -1):

you use `lodash` for this:

```
var _ = require("lodash");
var arr = [[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]], [8, [9, 10]]];
flatArr = _.flattenDeep(arr);
flatArr.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0);
```

Comment: what was the issue for giving `-1`?

Comment: Possibly because the additional dependency is unnecessary.

Comment: I have provided an alternative solution. Which was not mentioned above